# Sort matrix of points in R to get a sequential vector for plotting the line on x-y plot

Tags: r, matrix, plot, line, convex-hull

I have a list of points for a convex hull, as a matrix, which looks like this:

```
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]   23   18
 [2,]    7    1
 [3,]   14   18
 [4,]   24    1
 [5,]   24   23
 [6,]   10   11
 [7,]   13   14
 [8,]    9    7
 [9,]    9   10
[10,]   12   11
[11,]   12   13
```

I also have a list of x-y coordinates for these points (UPD: each integer in the hull corresponds to both x and y indices). Now I want to plot the convex hull with a single `lines()` call. How do I 'unwind' the point matrix, so that it looks like this: `c(23, 18, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 7, 1, 24)`?

Comment: I don't understand how the expected output is connected to the input.

Comment: I think I see it... but is row 10 a typo? Shouldn't it be `11  12` not `12  11`? And Rows 8 and 2 also seem backwards.

Comment: @GregorThomas no typos here; that is a legit output of `geometry::convhulln()`$hull

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want the paths of a graph starting from vertex 1? Package `igraph` can do that.

```
library(igraph)

g <- graph_from_data_frame(mat)
p <- all_simple_paths(g, from = V(g)[1], mode = "all")
```

The following gives the lengths of all paths in list `p`. We are looking for the longest.

```
lengths(p)
#[1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
```

It seems obvious from the lengths above that they are the same paths with different starting vertices and that the longest are the last one and the one in the middle of the list `p`.

```
p[[length(p)/2]]
#+ 11/11 vertices, named, from 0bc39f7:
# [1] 23 24 1  7  9  10 11 12 13 14 18
p[[length(p)]]
#+ 11/11 vertices, named, from 0bc39f7:
# [1] 23 18 14 13 12 11 10 9  7  1  24
```

**Data**

```
x <- textConnection('
23   18
7    1
14   18
24    1
24   23
10   11
13   14
9    7
9   10
12   11
12   13
')
mat <- read.table(x)
close(x)
```

Comment: that's fine; but i'm gonna run this calculation for thousand of hulls for several hours, and something tells me that is gonna be a huge overkill to calculate a full graph each time; i need a lighter solution

Answer (score 1):

UPD: This is the (correct) solution I came up with:

```
require(data.table)
find.nodes <- function(nodes) {
  exit.nodes <- which(duplicated(nodes[,1]))
  nodes <- cbind(nodes[exit.nodes, ncol(nodes):1], nodes[exit.nodes-1])
  setorder(nodes)
  return(nodes)
}
nodes <- rbind(hull, hull[, 2:1], use.names=FALSE)
setorder(nodes)
nodes <- find.nodes(nodes)
while (nrow(nodes) > 2) {
  nodes <- find.nodes(nodes)
}
nodes <- nodes[1,]
nodes <- unique(as.integer(nodes))
nodes <- c(nodes, nodes[1])
nodes
```

```
Unit: milliseconds
               expr      min       lq      mean   median       uq     max neval
   igraph.fun(hull) 0.875800 0.910251 0.9785159 0.921701 0.952600 97.3383 10000
 setnodes.fun(hull) 1.931201 1.989401 2.1007707 2.011601 2.054401 23.4761 10000
```

It is slower than `igraph` solution.
btw, `igraph::convex.hull$resverts` seems to output some strange result.

Comment: The times difference should go up with the data size. Upvote.

Comment: @RuiBarradas i updated the solution. now it is way slower